# log.Fatal with go command

Tags: go

I'm running a script which opens an http port. I initially had it logging errors:

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":7777", router))
```

I have additional code so I want to run it on another thread:

```
go http.ListenAndServe(":7777", router)
```

I still want to log any information related to the http port failing, but neither work:

```
go log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":7777", router))
```

Or

```
log.Fatal(go http.ListenAndServe(":7777", router))
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
go func() {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":7777", router))
}()
```